# How to change names of files in String[]

Tags: java, android

I have such code...

```
        File fileDir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/dd");
         if(!fileDir.exists() || !fileDir.isDirectory()){
             return;
         }
         String[] files = fileDir.list();
```

So, I have an array of files' names...
But I want to GET an array of `"path to each file"+fileDir.list()`

For example
I have - `"/09.jpg"`
I want - `"/mnt/sdcard/dd/09.jpg"`

How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: You are already have File fileDir with its fullPath (/mnt/sdcard/dd). You also can use fileDir.listFiles (return File[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code,

```
 String path = "/mnt/sdcard/dd";

 File fileDir = new File( path );

 if(!fileDir.exists() || !fileDir.isDirectory())
 {
     return;
 }

 String[] files = fileDir.list(); 

 for ( int i = 0 ; i < files.length ; i++  )
 { 
       files[i] = path + "/" +  files[i];
 }
```

Now the array files contains the updated value with path.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/dd09.jpg (No such file or directory)

Comment: _files[i] = path + "/"+ _files[i];

Comment: sorry, there was missing of "/" in my code, Now I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `getAbsolutePath()`,

```
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/dd");
Files[] files = file.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    Log.e("Root Path of file:" + i, files[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but won't work with list(), since it returns a String array. It would work with listFiles() though.

Comment: @jcxavier - Oh, My mistake, I missed to edit files as a File[]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
     File fileDir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/dd");
     if(!fileDir.exists() || !fileDir.isDirectory()){
         return;
     }
     File[] files = fileDir.listFiles(); 
     for(File f: files){
          Log.i("", f.getAbsolutePath()); 
     }
```